# Using Webhooks with API.AI (Mashape)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to know how to code and deploy API's obtained from Mashape, and use them as fulfillment in Api.ai.

Thanks a million for you response.

Answer (score 0):

You can fulfill an intent by having the response for each intent satisifed by your mashapge url.
For integration via webhooks/api's , api.ai allows your to configure only 1 URL/Domain.
If you have multiple mashape APIs you will not be able to serve multiple intents with different urls.